Java ForkJoinPool thread pool will inexplicably terminate running
Why does my code inexplicably interrupt execution when I use ForkJoinPool's default thread pool, but I don't encounter this problem when I use ExecutorService's custom thread pool
Default ForkJoinPool Example
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(1000);
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                    list.add("test" + j);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + j);
                }
                return list;
            });
            lists.add(future);
        }
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(lists.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        allFuture.thenRun(() -> {
            System.out.println("done");
        });

Use Custom ExecutorService's
int threadNum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadNum, threadNum, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(1000);
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            list.add("test" + j);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + j);
        }
        return list;
    },executorService);
    lists.add(future);
}
CompletableFuture<Void> allFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(lists.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
allFuture.thenRun(() -> {
    System.out.println("done");
});

When I tried to use CompletableFuture to batch obtain compressed package parsing and perform business operations, there were no problems when the data volume was within 100. However, when the data volume was 88, my program ended in an unknown situation; I am trying to replicate the online issue using a case study locally; At first, I tried using the join() method, and it was indeed successful without termination; But I later discovered that if I use a custom thread pool, it is not allowed to work with the join() method at all. I am very confused about how ForkJoinPool works at the bottom layer; Why did such differences occur; I understand that I did not use the Join() method, the main thread method was executed directly; Not waiting for my sub thread; But I used a thread pool and didn't have this problem. Why is that?
